# Changing soft input mode in activity

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an activity with one EditText. I would like to use both approaches for showing keyboard during my operations:

1. SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
2. SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE

I use this:

```
            if (something()) {
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
            } else {
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
            }
```

but it needs recreating (change device orientation) to work properly (for the first condition - setting to SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN because the second works properly). How can I do that programmatically?

Comment: Try merging both flags like : `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

Answer (score 2):

Ok I've just found a solution for my problem. android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in AndroidManifest is needed in this situation. I thought that it's not needed as I change this programmatically but it is. Now it works properly without additional recreation.